# Start-Process "Access is denied" when assigning to varriable

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am receiving an `Access is denied` error when I execute the following:

```
$result = Start-Process -PassThru -Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\...' -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\...'
```

If I don't assign it to a variable, it executes without the error. So **this works**:

```
Start-Process -PassThru -Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\...' -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\...'
```

And everything works, if executed as admin.

## Question

1. How to get a `Start-Process`'s `ExitCode`, as a regular user (non-admin)?
2. What permissions are required to assign the process to a variable?

## Currently

Start-Process without variable: User & Admin Successful

Start-Process **with** variable: **User Fails**, Admin Successful

Comment: The mere act of assigning the result cannot possibly result in an access denied, unless something *really* interesting is going on. What do you do with `$result` afterwards? `$result.ExitCode` should not be a problem; other properties may well be. And what happens if you assign `$banana` instead (just in case `$result` has been reserved somewhere, somehow?)

Comment: What is the app and the arguments?  I tried this with notepad and it worked fine.

Comment: @JeroenMostert only using it for `ExitCode`. `$banana` doesn't work :P. I am worried about the permissions the exe is currently set at. Currently it only has "Read" & "Read & Execute" permission

Comment: @boxdog Tried it with notepad too, it works. I think it has to do with permissions of the exe or how it is run (because it works as admin)

Comment: Instead of assigning it to a variable, what happens if you wrap the whole thing in brackets?

Comment: Are you trying to execute a exe from 'unknown publisher'? I tried with '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"' which has digital signature and it works in both cases admin/user

Comment: also what is your current working directory, can you try adding `-WorkingDirectory "C:\temp"` argument while calling  `Start-Process`

Comment: @Kundan Nope same thing. Without variable it shows the process info. With variable it shows "Access Denied".

Comment: @Panomosh what would that look like ? `$result = (Start-Process ...)`?

Comment: Is the argumentlist pointing somewhere not readable by the current user?  Seeing the full filepath and argumentlist would help.

Comment: @js2010 Argument list is pointing to current directory of the script. In terms of permission, I think the `FilePath` exe can be a problem. Which I why I was asking about permissions above.

Comment: Can you run the filepath exe normally without start-process as that user?

Comment: @js2010 I just ran the process with CMD, and it works. And the powsershell `start-process` method works as User, IF I don't assign to variable. The minute I assign to variable, I get the error.